# npm install error with java

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, rebuild

While doing npm install , i am getting error related to node-gyp rebuild.
This is coming related to java package.
npm install is ran on 64 bit linux machine with jdk 1.8
Any pointers for this issue? Please find the logs below

## Logs

```
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "java"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! java@0.6.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.6.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the java package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs java
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls java
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /u01/app/e5/tst01/mripo/scripts/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: All the other dependencies are getting downloaded through npm. After that there is a node-gyp rebuild step. This is the one which is failing.

Answer (score 1):

What did the trick for me was running:

```
npm rebuild
```

and then again

```
npm install
```

I believe that one of the compiled dependencies was messed up and rebuilding fixed it.

Comment: The npm rebuild, solved the problem to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to run the following commands before trying to use 1.8:

```
./compile-java-code.sh
./compile-java8-code.sh
node-gyp configure build
npm test
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/java#java-18-support

Answer (score 0):

did you try to update your npm , it seems that you dont have it installed when you trying to install the preferred packages.

```
[sudo] npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: npm version is 3.7.3 and node version is v5.9.1.Failure is related to node-gyp rebuild for java module. npm ERR! java@0.6.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`